# tweepy: how to check for alt_text

Tags: tweepy

I need to check if a given tweet contains or not alt_text.

I'm trying with `API.get_status` operation, which, according to [its documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.get_status) contains a parameter to include alt_text:

> **include_ext_alt_text** – If alt text has been added to any attached media entities, this parameter will return an `ext_alt_text` value in the top-level key for the media entity.

However, all I get is:

```py
In [47]: status = api.get_status('1373498941732454402', include_ext_alt_text=True)

In [48]: status.entities['media']
Out[48]: 
[{'id': 1373498937332629507,
  'id_str': '1373498937332629507',
  'indices': [69, 92],
  'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ew-mAaMWgAMGTRF.jpg',
  'media_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ew-mAaMWgAMGTRF.jpg',
  'url': 'https://short_url.com',
  'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/pZjrWYNESI',
  'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/rowasc/status/1373498941732454402/photo/1',
  'type': 'photo',
  'sizes': {'thumb': {'w': 150, 'h': 150, 'resize': 'crop'},
   'medium': {'w': 718, 'h': 1200, 'resize': 'fit'},
   'small': {'w': 407, 'h': 680, 'resize': 'fit'},
   'large': {'w': 1226, 'h': 2048, 'resize': 'fit'}}}]
```

Notice that there is no `ext_alt_text` value. I don't find it as part of the status object neither. However, when converting status to string something appears:

```py
In [49]: 'alt_text' in str(status)
Out[49]: True
```

And when ussing `re` to get what follows `alt_text` in the string, some part of the alt_text starts to appear:

```py
In [58]: re.search(r'.{10,15}alt_text.{10,30}', str(status)).group()
Out[58]: " 'fit'}}, 'ext_alt_text': 'Bash looks furious, Shell "
```

How can I get alt_text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after debugging a little with pycharm, I found that alt_text is available in `status.extended_entities['media'][0]['ext_alt_text']`, where `status = api.get_status('1373498941732454402', include_ext_alt_text=True)`.

This can be None when no alt_text is present, and `extended_entities` migth not be available, so before accessing check if it does exists.

**UPDATE**
In adition to this, for compatibility reasons, some tweets that actually contain images may not contain this atribute, so to make sure, the API call need an extra parameter with respect to the mode:

```py
api.get_status('1373498941732454402', include_ext_alt_text=True, tweet_mode="extended")
```

You can read more about this particular point [in this tweepy discussion](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/discussions/1571#discussioncomment-627660).

Notice that:

> `tweet_mode` is applicable to every Twitter API v1.1 method / endpoint that retrieves Tweets, not just specifically to `API.get_status`

So, you should also check [this docs for extended tweets](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html)